# GC PubSub publisher.publish works on local IDE but not in docker container

Tags: java, docker, maven, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

When I try to publish messages using google clould pubsub, it works fine in my local IDE Eclipse but when I use the same code in docker container, it doesn't work.
The execution at publisher.publish(message).get(1L, Timeunit.MINUTES) hangs

When I use an ExecutorService to submit this same task, it throws TimeOutException
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 1 minutes (plus 2746930 nanoseconds delay) for com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture$InternalSettableFuture@b5df597c[status=PENDING]

I see Deamon threads - GAX-34, GAX-35 .... , grpc-default-worker-ELG, grpc-default-executor keep running for 10 minutes or so

code -

```
    TopicName topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    try {
        publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).setEnableMessageOrdering(true).build();
        // Message to be published
        pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(ByteString.copyFromUtf8("Hello, Pub/Sub!"))
                .putAttributes("Day", "Sunny").setOrderingKey("101").build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception while instantiating publisher: " + e);
    }
    
    ApiFuture<String> future = null;

        try {
            if (publisher != null) {
                    future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
                    if (future != null) {
                        Runnable task = () -> {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("\n" + "Message: " + future.get() + " published");
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        };
                        service.submit(task);
                    }
                    }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            retryCount++;
            System.out.println("Failed to publish message. Retrying...");
            Thread.sleep(RETRY_DELAY_MS);
        }
    }
```

pom.xml cfgs

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <version.build-helper-maven-plugin>3.4.0</version.build-helper-maven-plugin>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
            <version>26.26.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
        <version>1.125.11</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>gax</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>gax-httpjson</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.34.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>32.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
        <version>2.37.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax</artifactId>
        <version>2.37.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax-httpjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.37.0</version>
    </dependency>
```